# Merge all elements from Two Lists having the same Date and Id and sum up their Costs

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

We have two lists in Java, as shown below. And I need to get all elements from these two lists and if there is same `id` with the same `date we need to sum the` cost` of such elements in these lists.

```java
List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
List<A> listB = new ArrayList<>();
List<A> results = new ArrayList<>();
```

`listA`:

| Id | Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 11.65 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 | 12.65 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 | 13.65 |
| 3 | 2022-05-01 | 19.5 |

`listB`:

| Id | Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | 1.65 |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 134.65 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 | 12.65 |
| 2 | 2022-09-01 | 7.8 |
| 3 | 2022-06-01 | 3.65 |

The results should be

results list should be - >

| Id | Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 11.65 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | 1.65 |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 134.65 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 | 25.3* |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 | 13.65 |
| 2 | 2022-09-01 | 7.8 |
| 3 | 2022-05-01 | 19.5 |
| 3 | 2022-06-01 | 3.65 |

* (listA.cost + listB.cost this is based on date condition and id)

What I have tried till now is this

```java
Stream.concat(
        listA.stream().map(d -> new Result(d.getId(), d.getDate()), d.getCost()),
        listB.stream().map(b -> new Result(b.getId(), b.getDate(), b.getCost())
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am able to get all the data but after this step I need to get all the data and if there is same `date` and same `id` we need to sum up the `cost` from `listA` with the cost of `listB`

Comment: What have you attempted?  You need to show some effort here.

Comment: ```
  Stream.concat(A.stream().
                map(d -> new Result(d.getId(), d.getDate(), d.getCost()), B.stream().
                map(b -> new Result(b.getId(), b.getDate(), b.getCost()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
 ```

I am able to get all the data but after this step I need to get all the data and if there is same date and same id we need to sum up the cost from List A with the cost of listB

Comment: @Sam - you can add that code in your comment to the question, where it will be much easier to format - and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will work:

Our `A` class:

```
class A implements Comparable<A>{
  private int id;
  private String date;
  private double cost;

  public A(int i, String d, double c){
    id = i;
    date = d;
    cost = c;
  }

  public int getID(){
    return id;
  }

  public String getDate(){
    return date;
  }

  public double getCost(){
    return cost;
  }

  public void setCost(double c){
    cost = c;
  }

  @Override public int compareTo(A compareID) {
        int comp = (compareID).getID();
        return this.id - comp;
    }

  public String toString(){
    return id + " " + date + " " + cost;
  }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<A> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    List<A> results = new ArrayList<>();

    listA.add(new A(1, "2022-01-01", 11.65));
    listA.add(new A(2, "2022-02-01", 12.65));
    listA.add(new A(2, "2022-03-01", 13.65));
    listA.add(new A(3, "2022-05-01", 19.5));

    listB.add(new A(1, "2022-04-01", 1.65));
    listB.add(new A(1, "2022-05-01", 134.65));
    listB.add(new A(2, "2022-02-01", 12.65));
    listB.add(new A(2, "2022-09-01", 7.8));
    listB.add(new A(3, "2022-06-01", 3.65));

    results = listA;
    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < listB.size(); j++){
        if((results.get(i)).getDate().equals((listB.get(j)).getDate()) && (results.get(i)).getID() == (listB.get(j)).getID()){
          results.get(i).setCost(results.get(i).getCost() + listB.get(j).getCost());
          listB.remove(j);
          j -= 1;
        }
      }
    }
    results.addAll(listB);
    Collections.sort(results);
    System.out.println(results);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2022-01-01 11.65, 1 2022-04-01 1.65, 1 2022-05-01 134.65, 2 2022-02-01 25.3, 2 2022-03-01 13.65, 2 2022-09-01 7.8, 3 2022-05-01 19.5, 3 2022-06-01 3.65]
```

In our `A` class, we define our private instance variables, being `id`, `date`, `cost`, and set up constructors, accessors, and mutators for the class. We will also set up our own comparator so we can sort by ID.

In our main class, we set `results` equal to `listA`. Next, we use a nested for loop to iterate through both `results` and `listB`. If the `i`th element in `results` and the `j`th element in `listB` have the same `id` and `date`, we will add the values in `listA`, and delete that element in `listB`. Finally, if there are any elements left over in `listB`, we add them to `results`, and then sort the list.

This is not the most efficient approach as it involves a nested for loop and sorting, but this will work nonetheless.

I hope this answered your question! Please let me know if you have any further questions or clarifications :)

Comment: Using `record` would simplify this Answer.

Answer (score 2):

> get all the data and if there is same `date` and same `id` we need to sum up the cost from `listA` with the cost of `listB`

It can be achieved by grouping the data from the these list into an intermediate map. The key of this map should be an object that would be capable to incorporate `date` and `id`. There are several quick and dirty approaches like concatenate them as strings, but the correct way is to define a *record* (or a class). And the values of the intermediate map would represent a sum of costs that are mapped to the same combination of `date` and `id`.

Then we can create a stream over the entries of the auxiliary map, turn each entry into an object `A` and collect into a list.

That's how it can be implemented.

Define a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), `IdDate`, to use as a *key*:

```
public record IdDate(long id, LocalDate date) {}
```

```
List<A> listA =
    Arrays.asList(new A(1, LocalDate.parse("2022-01-01"), 11.65), // for Java 9+ use - List.of()
                  new A(2, LocalDate.parse("2022-02-01"), 12.65),
                  new A(2, LocalDate.parse("2022-03-01"), 13.65),
                  new A(3, LocalDate.parse("2022-05-01"), 19.5));
        
List<A> listB =
    Arrays.asList(new A(1, LocalDate.parse("2022-04-01"), 1.65), // for Java 9+ use - List.of()
                  new A(1, LocalDate.parse("2022-05-01"), 134.65),
                  new A(2, LocalDate.parse("2022-02-01"), 12.65),
                  new A(2, LocalDate.parse("2022-09-01"), 7.8),
                  new A(3, LocalDate.parse("2022-06-01"), 3.65));

List<A> results = 
    Stream
    .concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(                       // creating an intermediate map `Map<IdDate, Double>`
            a -> new IdDate(a.getId(), a.getDate()), // classifier fuction - generating a key
            Collectors.summingDouble(A::getCost)     // downstream collector - combining values mapped to the same key
        )
    )
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> new A(entry.getKey().id(),     // transforming an entry into an object `A`
                        entry.getKey().date(),
                        entry.getValue()))
    .toList();                                   // In earlier Java: .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
A{id=2, date=2022-09-01, cost=7.8}
A{id=2, date=2022-03-01, cost=13.65}
A{id=2, date=2022-02-01, cost=25.3}
A{id=3, date=2022-06-01, cost=3.65}
A{id=3, date=2022-05-01, cost=19.5}
A{id=1, date=2022-05-01, cost=134.65}
A{id=1, date=2022-04-01, cost=1.65}
A{id=1, date=2022-01-01, cost=11.65}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sPL)

Comment: Good Answer. One small thing: You already use `record` requiring Java 16+. You might as well use `List.of` requiring Java 9+ in the code rather than in the comments. I changed your code to use `toList()` for the same reason.

Comment: The Question requires sorting by `id` and then `date`. Add a call to `Stream#sort`, passing `Comparator.comparing( IdDate :: id ).thenComparing( IdDate :: date )`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `groupingBy` in combination with `reduce` to get what you want.

First, we're creating a groupingBy key (in your case, thats a class with `id` and `date`). We may as well create a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```java
record GroupByKey(int id, String date) {
    public static GroupByKey fromResult(Result result) {
        return new GroupByKey(result.id(), result.date());
    }
}
```

Note that I added a method named `fromResult`, which is able to convert a `Result` instance to its corresponding groupingBy key.

Then the following will do:

```java
Map<GroupByKey, Optional<Result>> result = Stream.of(a, b)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(groupingBy(
        GroupByKey::fromResult,
        reducing((l, r) -> new Result(l.id(), l.date(), l.cost() + r.cost()))
    ));
```

<sup>(using `static` imports from `java.util.stream.Collectors`)</sup>

What happens here, is the following.

- `flatMap(List::stream)` makes sure that each element of both lists are the subject of a new stream.
- Then `groupingBy` creates a `Map` with as key the `GroupingByKey` and as value a list with all corresponding `Result` instances. Now the only thing what needs to be done here, is take all elements from the list within the map, and create a single `Result` instance with all costs added to eachother.

Note that this yields a `Map<GroupByKey, Optional<Result>>`. The values of the map are `Optional<Result>`s rather than `Result`s, because if some entry value were an empty list, the reduction operation would yield no results, hence the `Optional`. However, since we're using `groupingBy`, it is simply not possible for any of the keys to have an empty `List` as associated value, because then the key should not have been created in the first place. So we can just execute `Optional::orElseThrow` to unwrap the `Optional`. This can be done with the `collectingAndThen` method:

```java
.collect(groupingBy(
    GroupByKey::fromResult,
    collectingAndThen(
        reducing((l, r) -> new Result(l.id(), l.date(), l.cost() + r.cost())),
        Optional::orElseThrow
    )
));
```

The result is a `Map<GroupingByKey, Result>`, but we only need the values, not the keys. A simple `values()` call on the map returns a `Collection<Result>`.

Comment: Good Answer. Two small things: Wrapping `Stream` and `.of` each to their own lines will be more readable. And, declaring `var` explicitly would clarify to the reader what data structure you are creating.